# only first element in checkbox is selected i need select all item on listview

Tags: android, checkbox, selectall

here is my code for check all items on listview. only first element in checkbox is selected i need select all item on listview

```
public void onCheckedChanged( Compound Button button View, boolean is Checked) {
        Check Box c b=(Check Box)find View By Id(R.id. c b List_hook);
        Text View ex=(Text View) find View By Id(R.id.t v list_name);


        if(is Checked)
        {

            for(integer I =1; I<=l v. get Child Count();I++)
            {
                l v. set Item Checked(I,true);
                test.add(ex . get Text().to String());
            }

        }
        if(!is Checked)
        {
            for(integer I=1;I<=l v. get Child Count();I++)
            {
               l v. set Item Checked(I,false);
                test.remove(ex . get Text(). to String());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer here i found very useful http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-checkbox-textview-listview/

Comment: just want to know, what tool are you using for development ?

Comment: @amit Vaghela Android studio

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
private ArrayList<Getter_Setter> user_list;    

checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            for (int i = 0; i < user_list.size(); i++) {
                user_list.get(i).setSelected(checkbox.isChecked());
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Getter_Setter Class:

```
private boolean Selected = false;

public boolean isSelected() {
    return Selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    Selected = selected;
}
```

Adapter Class:

```
mHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();

            user_info_list.get(getPosition).setSelected((isChecked));
        }
    });
```

Comment: only first row is checked remaining stay same plz help

Comment: Have you made a adapter class??

Comment: yes i made a custom adapter class extended from base adapter @ Amarbir Singh

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/89d1b958c753c899ae25cdaa8df0401f its my code with full activity plz review it @Amarbir Singh

Comment: @Shellz I am Looking to It. Give me some time!!